# Socket no. for every new telnet connection is not changing

Tags: c++, sockets, telnet, tcp

Here's the premiss:-
I wanna display the username for every telnet connection and disconnection. The telnet terminal displays a log of all activities that happen on my remotely connected microprocessor.
I've designed here with a method to check how to display the username from an existing log structure.

But during debugging, I observed that for every new telnet connection created or closed, my socket no continues to remain constant at 8.

Is telnet connection supposed to work that way conceptually?

Here's the snippet of the code:-

```
void connectTelnet()
{
   sockaddr_in       clientIn;
   INT               addressLength;
   INT32             socketNum;
   TEXT              stringMsg[200];

   socketNum = accept(telnet_data.server_socket, (sockaddr*)&client_in, &addressLength);

   if (socketNum != -1)             //right here, the socketNum = 8
   {
      this->initializeTelnetSocket((UINT8)socketNum);

      this->telnet_data.socket_data[socketNum].remote_ip_port =
            client_in.sin_port;
      this->telnet_data.socket_data[socketNum].remote_ip_address[0] =
            (UINT8)(client_in.sin_addr.s_addr >> 24);
      this->telnet_data.socket_data[socketNum].remote_ip_address[1] =
            (UINT8)(client_in.sin_addr.s_addr >> 16);
      this->telnet_data.socket_data[socketNum].remote_ip_address[2] =
            (UINT8)(client_in.sin_addr.s_addr >> 8);
      this->telnet_data.socket_data[socketNum].remote_ip_address[3] =
            (UINT8)(client_in.sin_addr.s_addr);
   //log username here
    ethernet.logEthernetConnection(
            TCP, TELNET, TELNET_PORT,
            telnet_data.socket_data[socketNum].remote_ip_address,
            telnet_data.socket_data[socketNum].remote_ip_port,
            (TEXT *)NULL, LOG_CONNECTED, 1);
      this->telnet_data.socket_data[socketNum].connected = TRUE;

      //Set tcp push flag in this socket. so that data will be sent quickly..
      ethernet.setTCPFlag(socketNum, TCP_FLAGS_PUSH);

      sprintf(stringMsg, "login: ");
      this->telnetSendMessage(socketNum, (UINT8*)stringMsg, strlen(stringMsg));
   }
   else
   {
      errorDialogue("\ntelnet socket accept fail\n");
   }
}


void quitTelnet(INT socketNum)
{
   // Bounds check the income data
   if ((socketNum < 0) || (socketNum >= NUM_SOCKETS))       //right here, the socketNum = 8
   {
      diagError("\ntelent socket close failure, invalid socket number");
      return;  // invalid socket we can't continue.
   }
   //log username here
   ethernet.logEthernetConnection( TCP, TELNET, TELNET_PORT,
         telnet_data.socket_data[socketNum].remote_ip_address,
         telnet_data.socket_data[socketNum].remote_ip_port,
         this->telnet_data.socket_data[socketNum].loginStorage,
         LOG_DISCONNECTED,672);         

   this->initializeTelnetSocket(socketNum);
   close(socketNum);
   terminal.sendClosePortSocketMessage(socketNum);
}



int accept(int socketNum, sockaddr * client_address, int * addressLength)
{
   sockaddr_in * in_address = (sockaddr_in *)client_address;
   int         ret_val;
   Uint        counter;

   // verify socket number is value
   if (socketNum < 0 || socketNum >= NUM_SOCKETS)
   {
      diagError("Invalid Socket Number");
      management.saveCallStack(getFramePtr());  // Debug code to find out who is sending us invalid sockets
      return SOCKET_ERROR;
   }

   if((socketData.sockets[socketNum].state == USED) && (socketData.sockets[socketNum].type == SOCK_STREAM))
   {
      if(socketData.sockets[socketNum].protocol.tcp.state == LISTENING)
      {
         // wait for a connection
         while(socketData.sockets[socketNum].protocol.tcp.num_children == 0)
         {
            OSTimeDly(5);
         }

         // get the connections socket number
         ret_val = socketData.sockets[socketNum].protocol.tcp.child_sockets[0];
         OSSchedLock();
         socketData.sockets[socketNum].protocol.tcp.num_children--;
         for(counter = 0; counter < socketData.sockets[socketNum].protocol.tcp.num_children; counter++)
         {
            socketData.sockets[socketNum].protocol.tcp.child_sockets[counter] =
                  socketData.sockets[socketNum].protocol.tcp.child_sockets[counter+1];
         }
         OSSchedUnlock();

         // fill in the client IP data
         in_address->sin_family = AF_INET;
         in_address->sin_addr.s_addr = ((UINT8)(socketData.sockets[ret_val].remote_ip_address[0]) << 24) |
               ((UINT8)(socketData.sockets[ret_val].remote_ip_address[1]) << 16) |
               ((UINT8)(socketData.sockets[ret_val].remote_ip_address[2]) << 8) |
               (UINT8)(socketData.sockets[ret_val].remote_ip_address[3]);
         in_address->sin_port = socketData.sockets[ret_val].remote_port;
         *addressLength = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
      }
      else
      {
         ret_val = SOCKET_ERROR;
      }

   }
   else
   {
      ret_val = SOCKET_ERROR;
   }

   return ret_val;
}
```

Comment: What happens when two clients are connected at the same time?

Comment: Yes, socket descriptor is going to be reused when closed/opened.